# Не работает виртуальный хост Nginx для контейнера LXC

Tags: nginx, lxc

Я создал контейнер с помощью LXC и развернул в нем приложение. Контейнер имеет IP 10.0.3.211, внутри установлен и запущен Nginx, который слушает порт 80. Для него я прописал виртуальный хост следующего вида:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name sitename.ru;

    root /home/ubuntu/www/sitename;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri /index.php =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Если вне контейнера я выполню команду

```
curl -X GET http://10.0.3.211:80
```

то получу главную страницу своего приложения. Но я хочу получить доступ к своему приложению, используя домен sitename.ru.

Снаружи также установлен и запущен Nginx. Для него я прописал виртуальный хост следующего вида:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name sitename.ru;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_pass http://10.0.3.211:80;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

В файле /etc/hosts я прописал домен sitename.ru:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       ns16-X553MA
...
127.0.0.1       sitename.ru
...

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Но если я также вне контейнера выполню команду

```
curl -X GET http://sitename.ru
```

то получу не главную страницу своего приложения, а страницу с заголовком Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page: It works. При этом Apache остановлен.

Команда

```
curl -X GET -v http://sitename.ru
```

выводит

```
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, GET is already inferred.
* Rebuilt URL to: http://sitename.ru/
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to sitename.ru (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: sitename.ru
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: nginx/1.10.3
< Date: Sat, 24 Jun 2017 05:00:19 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 11321
< Connection: keep-alive
< Last-Modified: Sun, 18 Jun 2017 07:36:47 GMT
< ETag: "59462d8f-2c39"
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< 
...
```

В чем моя ошибка?

Comment: Эээ апач? А где вы правили etc/hosts?

Comment: Файл /etc/hosts я правил в основной системе.

Comment: Там где curl запускался?

Comment: Да, curl я выполнял тоже в основной системе.

Comment: `curl -v -X GET ...` и смотрите куда же таки он идёт

Comment: Добавил вывод этой команды с опцией -v в описание. Но я не понимаю, что в нем не так. Запрос идет на домен sitename.ru на хосте 127.0.0.1 и порте 80, как и прописано в виртуальном хосте.

Comment: Копать логи nginx. Вы его перезапустили?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблему удалось решить, прописав домен sitename.ru в файле /etc/hosts внутри контейнера:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   container_name
127.0.0.1   sitename.ru

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```